# Show "duplicate Number" when number is not found in range

Tags: vba, excel

```
If MoneyTextBox.Value = range("H:H").Find(MoneyTextBox.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Duplicate number"
EndIf
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or simply this...

```
If Application.CountIf(Range("H:H"), MoneyTextBox.Value) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Duplicate number"
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(CLng(MoneyTextBox.Value), Range("H:H"), 0)) Then
    MsgBox "Duplicate number"
EndIf
```

Comment: Why `Not IsError` and not directly `IsNumeric`?

Comment: @DirkReichel I use the compact form `ISNUMBER` in Excel formulas but in VBA especially for SO answers I prefer the more "explicit" form. But both are good.

Comment: But the output can only be numeric or an error. That way `IsNumeric` isn't less explicit than `Not IsError` :P

Comment: Yeah but `IsError` clearly spots "no match" for the code reader :)

Comment: More like a habit to look for "not no match". I was just curious if there is a "technical" reason...  ;)

Answer (score 2):

The [`Find` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-find-method-excel) does not return the found text, but the first cell where the text was found, and when it is not found it returns `Nothing`. Furthermore, your Range has numbers (going by the title of your question), while your form might have a text input box (the question is not clear on that). Your condition is going to be false each time because of this.

Instead, convert the text input to number, and use the fact that the `Find` method returns `Nothing` when the text is not found:

Change this:

```
If MoneyTextBox.Value = range("H:H").Find(MoneyTextBox.Value) Then
```

to:

```
If Not Range("H:H").Find(CLng(MoneyTextBox.Value)) Is Nothing Then
```